# projective model structure on presheaves , hom-functors are always cofibrant

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, enriched-category-theory

Why hom-functors are always cofibrant in the [projective model structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+functors) in $[\cal T,\cal V]$? The claim is [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0422.pdf) on page 5.

Comment: This is probably using the assumption that all objects of $V$ are cofibrant.

Comment: But natural transformations in $[\cal T,\cal V]$ are cofibrant if the components i.e. arrows in $\cal V$ are cofibrations,not objects.Moreover, projective model structure speak about fibrations,and not cofibrations.

Comment: Cofibrant is an adjective that applies to objects, I have no idea what you mean by a cofibrant natural transformation.